# CORS failed when upload file to cloud storage using firebase sdk

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cors, vuejs3

im use Firebase SDK upload a file to Cloud Storage from Vue3, below is my code:

```
import { 
 uploadBytes,
 FirebaseStorage,
 getStorage
} from 'firebase/storage'
import { firebaseApp } from '@/firebase'

const storage = getStorage(firebaseApp);

function upload(file, group) {
    const storagePath = `downloads/${group}/files/${file.filename}`;
    const fileRef = ref(storage, storagePath);
    uploadBytes(fileRef, file);
}
```

but i get this:

[Screenshot of CORS Error in browser( image )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVF6g.png)

[Request: firebase URL ( image )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cOqE.png)

[Request Header:'Provisional headers are shown'( image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iO11R.png)

[Screenshot of the  Request in the browser ( image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dn5pl.png)

[Response from firebase :"" (is empty)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSiwI.png)

I think this error comes from CORS, and i see this document to learn how to setting CORS on cloud storage:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files

this is my cors.json:

```
[
 {
    "origin": ["*"],
    "method": ["*"],  // or ['GET']
    "maxAgeSeconds": 1800
  }
]
```

then I waited 30 minutes, and i try upload again,
But this didn't help, same error.

How to fix it to upload?